# Android: Move whole layout upwards

Tags: android

I have a LinearLayout, when user selects my AutoCompleteTextView(ACTW) I want to move the whole layout upwards, so that the ACTW is at the top and there is space between the ACTW and software keyboard for suggestions. 1) How to do this? 2) How to make this animated (but this is not necessary)?

Answer (score 0):

This: `<activity android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">` sounds like what you need.

See [this page](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html) for more info.

Comment: This moves the AutoCompleteTextView only if it's hidden by soft. keyboard.

Comment: How does that differ from what you need?

Comment: Now, the AutoCompleteTextView is about 50px above the software keyboard, so there isn't enough place for the suggestions dropdown (only one suggestion is visible).